# How to create a table with only integers

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a table with taxonomy [chr] and presence/absebce data [num] for the sample. I imported it from .tsv file. It is a table with x observations and y variables. I have to convert it to be a table only with integers as entries.

I tried `lapply(data,as.integer)`, it works for columns with presence/absence data, but in the taxonomy column, my data dissapered and I have NA instead of the species. What is more, I don't have a table anymore, but a list with y variables.

Any other way I can do this?

| taxonomy | site1 | site2 | site3 | site4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| species1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| species2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| species3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

After `lapply(data,as.integer)` it looks like that:

| taxonomy | site1 | site2 | site3 | site4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| NA | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| NA | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: `lapply(data[,2:5],as.integer)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I need this first column to be in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can do...

```r
library(dplyr)

# everything except the first column
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(-1, as.integer))

# everything except "taxonomy"
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(-taxonomy, as.integer))

# everything that starts with "site"
data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("site"), as.integer))
```

I would question what is in your data to make it read as character though in the first place. My guess is there is some "NA" character. If you are using `read.table()`, you may want to adjust the argument `na.strings = "NA"` to have it read in as integer in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use base R, we can use lapply and assign the output to just a subset of the data:

```
data[-1]<-lapply(data[-1], as.integer)
data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know where the problem is now - I need to make this first column with taxonomy names as labels in my table.

Reading the data with `read.csv('data.csv', header = TRUE, row.names = 1)` actually helped.